# Validator always return empty in graphql

Tags: javascript, validation, graphql

the problem is, I am not able to make a request to MongoDB after validating the request with the following code:

```
module.exports.validateRegisterInput = (
  username,
  email,
  password,
  confirmPassword
) => {
  const errors = {};

  if (username.trim() === "") {
    errors.username = "Username must be provided";
  }
  if (email.trim() === "") {
    errors.email = "Email must be provided";
  } else {
    const validEmail =
      /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
    if (!email.match(validEmail)) {
      errors.email = "Email must be valid";
    }
  }
  if (password === "") {
    errors.password = "Password must be provided";
  }
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    errors.password = "Passwords must match";
  }

  return {
    errors,
    vaild: Object.keys(errors).length < 1,
  };
};
```

the validators work fine and check the request for any mistakes but once there is no issue with the request it does not let me send a request and raises an error anyway, also I am using the validators in the following way:

```
module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    async register(
      parent,
      { registerInput: { username, email, password, confirmPassword } }
    ) {
      const { valid, errors } = validateRegisterInput(
        username,
        email,
        password,
        confirmPassword
      );

      if (!valid) {
        throw new UserInputError("Errors", { errors });
      }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

so, I solved the problem, the problem was I was not calling the question directly and changed it to:

```
validateRegisterInput(username, email, password, confirmPassword);
```

and add errors in the validators and not in the index

```
const { UserInputError } = require("apollo-server");

module.exports.validateRegisterInput = (
  username,
  email,
  password,
  confirmPassword
) => {
  if (username.trim() === "") {
    throw new UserInputError("Username must be provided", {
      errors: {
        username: "Username must be provided",
      },
    });
  }
  if (email.trim() === "") {
    throw new UserInputError("Email must be provided", {
      errors: {
        email: "Email must be provided",
      },
    });
  } else {
    const validEmail =
      /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
    if (!email.match(validEmail)) {
      throw new UserInputError("Email must be correct", {
        errors: {
          email: "Email must be correct",
        },
      });
    }
  }
  if (password === "") {
    throw new UserInputError("Password must be provided", {
      errors: {
        password: "Password must be provided",
      },
    });
  }
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    throw new UserInputError("Passwords must match", {
      errors: {
        password: "Password must match",
      },
    });
  }
};
```